# SQl Server 2005 Datatype

Tags: sql-server-2005

What's best datatype for storing tax rate in SQl Server 2005?

Comment: Best for my bank account to store it as NULL ;)

Comment: Then Balance * TaxRate == NULL :(

Comment: Luckily that's the calculation for how much tax I'll need to pay :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258832(v=SQL.80).aspx), I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Because you play with money [smallmoney](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933242%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx) could be the best option.